# Loopback testing with supertest, mocha and models

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, loopbackjs, supertest

On the [Google groups post on deprecating loopback-testing](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/w038RvqHeYI) there is a question that asks about providing a proper example of how testing can be achieved without loopback-testing. That thread talks about using [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) instead.

Below is an attempt that I made to combine Mocha, supertest along with models ([from app.js](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/blob/master/example/simple-data-source/app.js)). The result works really well when I run the file by itself. But if I had another test file (say test-teacher.js) then the first test file (call it test-student.js) starts to fail in weird ways I can't describe.

Am I missing something or can models not be used like I am using them below?

```
describe('/Student', function () {

    var server = require('../server/server')
    var loopback = require('loopback')
    var supertest = require('supertest')
    var request = require('supertest')(server)

    var dataSource = server.dataSource('db', {adapter: 'memory'})

    var Student = dataSource.define('Student', {
        'id': Number,
        'points': Number
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        Student.updateOrCreate({id: 1, points: 5000});
    })


    it('Post a new student', function (done) {
        request.post('/api/Students').send({points: 5000}).expect(200, done)

    })


})
```

Comment: Where are you getting the `dataSource` variable from? In any case, multiple files in the same test run all share memory, which means you also share in-memory model definitions and data. My guess is that you start up your LB app somewhere in there, yes? You need to make sure to close that down, but the data may still persist. That would be my guess.

Comment: Excellent catch. Cut and paste error. Added `dataSource` declaration. WRT to starting up LB app, I don't do it explicitly. The above code can be run with `mocha test/test-student.js`. And then I can run all the tests with `mocha test`. By defining request with the server, it calls LB.

Comment: So ... turns out that in the second file test-teacher.js I also defined `Student`. When I comment out `Student` in test-teacher.js the test above works. Then obviously the test in test-teacher.js fails because it doesn't now about `Student`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on feedback from jakerella on the previous answer, I changed the code above so that I don't have to redefine the models from scratch in the code (thanks jakerella!)

With the code below, I am able to run all the tests from multiple different models as a single suite using `npm test` without any failures.

Since I am interested in only individual orders ... listen and close were not necessary. I suspect that if I was testing overall instances of models that were created it would become required.

```
describe('/Student', function () {

    var server = require('../server/server')
    var request = require('supertest')(server)
    var expect = require('expect.js')

    var Student 

    before(function() {
        Student = server.models.Student    
    })

    beforeEach(function (done) {
        Student.upsert({id: 1, points: 5000}, function() { done() })
    })    

    it('Post a new student', function (done) {
        request.post('/api/Students').send({points: 5000}).expect(200, done)
     })
})
```

Comment: Apart from a few typos that I just fixed, this is actual very helpful. Especially the `var request = require('supertest')(server)` so that in the tests you can simply do `request.post('/api/Students')`.

Answer (score 8):

Wanted to toss this into an answer... the first issue was an undefined `dataSource` var, but then you also had redefined `Student` in your two tests. My recommendation instead is used the LoopBack app and models already defined (usually in `common/models/`).Then the basic implementation for testing (that I use) is something like the code below (using `mocha` and `chai`). Note the `beforeEach` and `afterEach` to start and stop the server.

```
var assert = require('chai').assert,
    superagent = require('superagent'),
    app = require('../server/server');

describe('Person model', function() {
  var server;

  beforeEach(function(done) {
    server = app.listen(done);
  });

  afterEach(function(done) {
    server.close(done);
  });

  it('should log in and log out with live server', function(done) {
    superagent
      .post('http://localhost:3000/api/People/login')
      .send({ email: 'john@doe.com', password: 'foobar' })
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .end(function(err, loginRes) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }

          assert.equal(loginRes.status, 200);
          assert.ok(loginRes.body);
          assert.equal(loginRes.body.userId, 1);
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Please provide example code of using the models already defined in `common/models/`.

Comment: That *is* the example code... ? If your LoopBack server has models in it, then they'll come through via the `server.js` file! Try looking on the [docs site](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+models) for how to define models.

Comment: I reference `Student.updateOrCreate` which means that there needs to be a reference to `Student`. As a result, don't I need to declare `Student` within the test? Something like `var Student =` something?

Comment: If `Student` is part of your application, shouldn't you define it in your application? I'm not sure why you're defining models in your tests... your models are part of your LoopBack application!

Comment: Yes ... totally agree. Since `Student` is defined via JSON, how do I access the Looopback `Student` model?

Comment: Aaah... `app.models.Student`

Comment: When I change to use the definitions in `app.model.Student` and listen and close the server, calls to `findById` return null resulting in errors like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of null`

Comment: Yeah, it will return `null` from a `findById()` if there are no matches to that ID.

Comment: I think it needs to call done even if err doesn't occur.